# Fastest algorithm to construct a proper edge $(\Delta(G)+1)$-coloring of a simple graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, graph-colorings, combinatorial-optimization

A proper edge coloring is a coloring of the edges of a graph so that adjacent edges receive distinct colors. Vizing's theorem states that every simple graph $G$ has a proper edge coloring using at most maximum degree plus one colors. In [1], the authors showed that there is an $O(mn)$-time algorithm to construct a proper edge $(\Delta(G)+1)$-coloring of a simple graph whth $m$ edges and $n$ vertices. I wonder whether there is a faster algorithm to construct such an edge coloring.

[1] J. Misra, and D. Gries. A constructive proof of Vizing’s theorem.Inform. Process. Lett.41(3)131–133 (1992)

Comment: There are various places (including other papers and the Wikipedia articles https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vizing's_theorem and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misra_%26_Gries_edge_coloring_algorithm) where one can find a citation to an unpublished 1985 tech report by Gabow, Nishizeki, Kariv, Leven, & Terada with the time $O(m\sqrt{n\log n})$. I can't find an online copy of the tech report itself, don't have a copy, and don't know how widely it is still believed (given its unpublished status).

Comment: Type “Gabow Nishizeki” into Google and one of the top links should be to a site called “documen.site” from which you can download the 54 page PDF. The site looks a bit dodgy, butI don’t think a 35 year old tech report would create any copyright issues. But you may want to make sure that no malware is piggybacking on the download.

Comment: I just find a prinprint on Arxiv (arXiv:1907.03201v4). An $O(m\sqrt{n})$-time algorithm is provided. I didn't check the proof and so I am not sure whether it is correct.